# Calculate length of a string input

Tags: java

I made a program that calculates the length of a string that the user inputs. My program works fine for the most part but when I print "Hello World", it gives the length 5 (whereas it should be 11). How can I fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StringLength {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the string: \n");
            String word = in.next();

            System.out.println("The length is: " +word.length());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StringLength {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the string: \n");
            String word = in.nextLine(); <----// change it to this

            System.out.println("The length is: " +word.length());

    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you should avoid answering as this is a duplicate of so many previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String word = in.nextLine()` instead `String word = in.next()`

Answer (score 0):

`in.next()` only reads the first token. In your case "Hello".

You have to use `in.nextLine()` to read the whole string.